# Why JDK7 not allow method local Inner Class to access its own method's local variables

Tags: java, inner-classes

```
class MyOuter2{
private String x;
void doStuff(){
    int mloc= 100;
    x ="Outer class variable";
    class MyInner{
        public void seeOuter(){
            System.out.println("Access both: " + x+" and " + mloc);
            System.out.println("Inner class ref is " + this);
            System.out.println("Outer class ref is " + MyOuter2.this);
        }
    }
    MyInner MethodInnerClass = new MyInner();
    MethodInnerClass.seeOuter();

  }
}

public class InnerClass {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyOuter2 outer = new MyOuter2();
      outer.doStuff();
   }
}
```

In this code I use doStuff()'s variable mloc in method local MyInner Class 
my compiler compile this code and also run this code through JDK8.

Answer (score 1):

In Java SE 8, a local class can access local variables and parameters of the enclosing block that are **final** or **effectively final**. A variable or parameter whose value is never changed after it is initialized is *effectively final*.

Answer (score 0):

Method-local inner class variable can access in Java 8, but not Java 7.
I use java version "1.8.0_31", and it can compile. But it cannot compile in Java 7.

Comment: Yes after I installs **JDK 8** this problem is no longer exist.